# Is there a mailgun api for dns check?

Tags: mailgun

When I am creating a new domain using the API, the status of the domain remains unverified until I go to the website and click the button "Check DNS Records Now".

Are there any APIs for this?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do this right now (I've spoken with support), but there is a feature request that you can vote on here:

https://mailgun.uservoice.com/forums/156243-general/suggestions/7664346-add-an-api-based-dns-check

Comment: Can verify after being in contact with mailgun support that this is still case.